# How to get value of a particular input in ngform

Tags: angular

```
<form #apiForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(apiForm);">
    <div class="apply-form">
    <div>
    <label>API Name <span class="astrik">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="e.g presonal key" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div>
</form>
```

I want to get the value of input so that I could validate it.

```
 onSubmit(apiForm: any) {
    console.log(apiForm.controls.name.value)
    console.log(apiForm.name.value)
    if(apiForm.name.value) {
      alert()
    }
  }
```

Comment: why don't you use formBuilder: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder in angular

Comment: @zuyi Please describe more explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Here, you are using template driven forms,

We need to explicitly register each template control with the `ngForm` directive. To do so we need to do two things to each template form control:

Add the `ngModel` directive
Add the name attribute

```
<form #apiForm="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(apiForm);">
    <div class="apply-form">
    <div>
    <label>API Name <span class="astrik">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="e.g presonal key" name="name" ngModel/>
    </div>
    <div>
</form>
```

you can get the json object of form by using `apiForm.value`.

and instead of using validation in function, I will recommend you to use form control states and add validation message on template.

Refer [Template Driven Forms in Angular](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular/tutorial/template-driven-forms/)

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Answer (score 0):

use [(ngModel)] for your input:-

```
<input type="text" placeholder="e.g presonal key" name="name" 
[(ngModel)]="apiForm.name"/>
```

on Typescript file declare `apiForm`

```
 apiForm = {
    name:''
 }

 onSubmit(apiForm: any) {
   console.log(apiForm.controls.name.value)
   console.log(apiForm.name.value)
   if(apiForm.name.value) {
     alert()
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You can achieve this using ngModel. don't forget to import FormsModule in your app.module.ts file.


    <input type="text" placeholder="e.g presonal key"
        [(ngModel)]="apiForm.name"/>

        apiForm={name:null};

        onSubmit(apiForm: any) {
           console.log(this.apiForm.name)              
           }
```